# Are there any common allelopathic plants suitable as a pre-lawn winter cover crop?

Tags: weed-control, lawn, cover-crop

Being March in the Southern hemisphere, winter is approaching. I have just had my very-weedy front yard levelled. Most of the weeds have been removed, but I don't want to sow grass until I've given some of the remaining weed stalks a chance to show themselves so I can dig them out.

I'm thinking about sowing lupins to cover the ground in the meantime. I think lupins would have the added advantage of growing relative quickly (as the seeds are large).

Are there any alternative winter cover crops that have [allelopathic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allelopathic) properties (so would prevent or slow growth of at least some of the weeds).

I'm in New Zealand, with a moderate climate. Temperatures will range roughly between -5 (overnight) and 15 C over the winter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Winter rye is allelopathic, inexpensive, and very hardy. I don't know about suitability as "pre lawn". It can be challenging to kill in the spring when you're ready to plant. I rototill it once or twice, then wait a couple of weeks before trying to plant any seeds.

I'm not sure about sowing lupins -- it wouldn't work well for me because we'd be hitting -5°C and down to -20°C in midwinter, but perhaps in your climate they will grow enough in the fall. They have the added advantage of fixing nitrogen and being relatively easy to kill in the spring.